# How do I eliminate excess columns and rows in my excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I only want 5 columns in my excel sheet. I want the rest GONE! When I press and hold control and the arrow buttons, then delete and save (as I read as one suggestion on your page,) it auto populates the same rows. How can I have ONLY 5 columns??? Thank you.

Comment: You will need to hide the other columns.  They will always come back empty if deleted.

Comment: @kat, I think that only some view or security settings can help in this case. But I am not sure what is the purpose of this request. Can you please offer some simple sample or more information? Example of what you want to reach...

Answer (score 3):

The first five columns are A, B, C, D, E...

1. Click the F in the column header, so that you make the column be "selected".
2. Now hit the <kbd>End</kbd>-key, then
3. hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and hit <kbd>=></kbd> (i.e. cursor right!).
   This should have made ALL the columns from F all the way to the very last column be selected.
4. Now, place the mouse pointer over the column heading
   (where F was, on whatever the last column is labelled as),
5. Click the right side mouse button and select "Hide".

Comment: Ha, that's great, I've never tried to do that before. Now cue a confused question in a few hours "My Excel sheet only has 5 columns, why can't I enter data to the right any more?"

Comment: + the same can be done to rows. To "unhide" select the rightmost column, right-click and select "unhide". Libreoffice: CTRL-cursor-right equals "End"+Right-cursor in excel.